# JqGrid Performance - setRowData lags

Tags: performance, jqgrid

`setRowData` takes almost 5 seconds when the grid has 300 rows, 30 cols, and 4 frozen cols.

```
$("#tbl").jqGrid({
    gridview: true,
    url: '../controller/GetData',
    datatype: "json",
    rowNum: pageSize,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadtext: '',
    loadui: 'disable',
    rowList: [1000, 2000, 3000],
    width: $(window).width() - LeftMargin,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    pager: '#dvPager',
    pagerpos: 'left',
    colNames: GetColNames(selectedViewName, viewCols),
    colModel: GetColModel(selectedViewName, viewCols),
    cmTemplate: {
        title: false
    },
    recordtext: "Displaying {0} - {1} of {2}",
    rowattr: function (rowData) {

    },
    //onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
    //    e.stopPropagation();
    //    proto.editcell(rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e);
    //},
    loadComplete: function (data) {..},
    onPaging: function (data) {..},
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {..}
    });
```

Can you please guide me with the performance tuning tips?

In GetColModel we are binding columns as follows -

```js
'Discount': {
                name: 'Discount', index: 'Discount', width: colModelWidthDict['Discount'], title: false, sortable: false, resizable: colResizable, hidden: !bReadCalculationSellInfo,
                formatter: function (cellValue, option, rowObject) {
                    if (rowObject.level == 0 || (rowObject.Flag == 0 && (rowObject.Discountable && rowObject.Discountable.toLowerCase() == 'no')))
                        return '';
                    else {
                        if (!proto.IsReadOnly(rowObject) && ((rowObject.Flag == 0 && (rowObject.Discountable && rowObject.Discountable.toLowerCase() == 'yes')) || rowObject.Flag > 0))
                            
                            return proto.GetControls("Discount", option.rowId, "Numeric", rowObject.Discount, 6, 90)
                        else
                            return '<span class="amt">' + cellValue + '</span>';
                    }
                },
                unformat: function (cellValue, option) {
                    return cellValue;
                },
                cellattr: function (rowId, val, rowObject, cm, rdata) {
                    if (parseInt(rowObject.PPPChngDisc) == 1)
                        return ' style="color:red"';
                }
            }
```

//code for colModel - 1 column above

Comment: The code which you posted **don't contain any call of `setRowData`** where you have problems. It's important that you include the part of the code or at least to describe details where and when in your code you use the method. **Why you need to call `setRowData` multiple times?** The code like `rowNum: pageSize` or `colModel: GetColModel(selectedViewName, viewCols)` provides no information. In the same way you could wrote "my code" without including the code. Do you use data paging or not? How many rows in the page? (20, 300 or 3000)? How many rows of data you need to display?

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use? Which fork of jqGrid you use?** After jqGrid 4.7 exist now only [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103532) forks. Which one you use?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..yes this is the configuration of jqgrid. I am calling setRowData on editing of one column, after calculation updating other columns in same row. Yes we are using data paging, in a page for now looking for 500 rows. in GetColModel we are dynamically binding columns. I am updating above with sample for one column.

Comment: JQGrid - jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid from Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com

Comment: @Oleg - Not using inlineEdit as it does not allow us to use setFrozenColumn. Not only setRowData is sluggish bit slowness while selecting scrollbars as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should prefer to modify only small number of rows. If you modify *one row* then the web browser have to recalculate position of all other rows (500 rows) of the grid. In the case modifying 300 rows means 300*500 operations for the web browser.

If you fill **the whole** grid and you use `gridview: true` option then jqGrid places at the beginning **all the data** for the grid body in array of strings. After preparing of all information in string format jqGrid place *the whole* body of the grid as one operation. It's just one assigning `innerHTML` property of `tbody`. Thus it's more effective to **reload** the whole grid as to make modification of many rows of the grid in the loop using `setRowData`.

So I would recommend you to reload the grid in your case.

Moreover you should consider to reduce the number of rows in the page of grid. If you use `rowNum: 500` you just reduce the performance of your page tin many times without any advantage for the user. The user can see about 20 rows of the data only. Only if the user scrolls he/she is able to see another information. In the same way the user could click next page button. Holding 500 rows force web browser make a lot of unneeded work. Modifying of the first row from 500 the web browser have to recalculate position of all 500 rows. Even if the user move the mouse over a row the web browser change the class of the hovering row and it have  to recalculate position of all other from 500 rows event the rows are not visible.

One more remark. The implementation of frozen columns in jqGrid 4.6 is slow. Starting with the end of 2014 and publishing 4.7.1 with changing Lisanse and making jqGrid commercial I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) as fork based on jqGrid 4.7 (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) for more details). I implemented a lot of changes and new features in the fork. The recent changes includes many improvement of frozen columns feature. If you loads free jqGrid or just try it directly from GitHub by including the corresponding URLs (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)) you will see that the performance of frozen columns is dramatically improved. Additionally frozen columns supports now row and cell editing in all editing modes. I plan to publish free jqGrid 4.9 soon. So I recommend you to try it.

**UPDATED:** You posted the code, which you use in comments below. I see the main problem in the implementation of `Process` function which will be called on change in the `<input>` fields on the grid. I recommend you to try something like this one:

```js
function Process(contrl) {
    var $cntrl = $(contrl),
        $td = $cntrl.closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
        $tr = $td.parent(),
        rowId = $tr.attr("id"),
        newValue = $cntrl.val(),
        $grid = $("#list"),
        p = $grid[0].p,
        colModel = p.colModel,
        columnName = colModel[$td[0].cellIndex].name, // name of column of edited cell
        localRowData = $grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowId),
        iColTotal = p.iColByName.total;

    // modify local data
    localRowData[columnName] = newValue;
    localRowData.total = parseInt(localRowData.quantity) * parseFloat(localRowData.unit);

    // modify the cell in the cell (in DOM)
    //$grid.jqGrid("setCell", rowId, "total", localRowData.total);
    $($tr[0].cells[iColTotal]).text(localRowData.total);
    return false;
}
```

One can event improve the code and not use `setCell` at all. It's important to understand that local grid hold the data in the form of JavaScript object. The access to the data is **very quickly**. You can modify the data without any side effects existing with DOM elements. In the above code I use only *relative* search inside of the DOM of the row using `closest` and `parent`. It works very quickly. I recommend to save `$("#list")` in the variable *outside* of the `Process` (move `var $grid = $("#list")` in the outer function) and just use `$grid` variable. It will make access to the DOM of page very quickly. The line `localRowData = $grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowId)` get **the reference** to internal JavaScript data object which represent the internal data of the row. By modifying the data by `localRowData[columnName] = newValue;` or `localRowData.total = ...` we make the half of job. One need only to change the value in the DOM on the cell Total. I used `iColByName` which exist in the latest sources of free jqGrid on GitHub. It get just the column index in `colModel` by column name. One can find the same information alternatively if one use more old jqGrid. The line `$($tr[0].cells[iColTotal]).text(localRowData.total);` shows how to assign manually the data in the cell. It's the most quick way to do this, but one assign the data *without the usage formatter*. For more common case (for example in case of frozen "total" column) one can use the commented row above: `$grid.jqGrid("setCell", rowId, "total", localRowData.total);`.

Comment: ok great!..so can we conclude that there is little scope of improvement with 4.6? I will try option free jqGrid with fork based on jqgrid4.7 and update.

Comment: @user4903642: I rewrote many parts of the code trying to hold the compatibility. Just try it and you can decide yourself how much improvement relative to 4.6 you will have. In any way you should don't forget about the first part of my answer. Editing of 300 rows from 500 will be still **very expensive**. I suppose that editing of 10 rows from 500 will be slowly as to reload the 500 rows.

Comment: @user4903642:  Depend on the other details of your implementation you can use `loadonce: true` or `datatype: "local"` (or `datatype: "jsonstring"`). In the case you will have `data` parameter which represent all 500 rows which you have. So you can modify the `data` array (300 rows) and reload the grid **locally** (reload from `data` array). It will be very quickly.

Comment: @Oleg-with reloadGrid there is not a significant difference in performance and I modified your freeGrid sample 'autoResizingPerformane1000' to my requirement and noticed sluggish performance with the sample as well. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XYPmpPQsTlpwmLSgHbzbr_AOrJXTvaOCs8Kk4Ze09Wk/edit?usp=sharing                                          Am I missing something?

Comment: One more update setCell seems to be faster however for the custom formatted cells rowObject coming from formatted definition is not fully populated ..do I need to call setCell in a specific fashion? If not setCell then any other alternative to directly update cell contents?

Comment: @user4903642: Could you provide a working demo which demonstrates what you do? I still don't understand what you want to test. The code which you posted don't includes any `setRowData` or `setCell` call which was your main question. I wrote you that the best performance advantage one would have if one replace  `rowNum: 500` (which should be never used in real projects) to `rowNum: 20` (or some other value which corresponds the place of the page). If you speak about `rowObject` then what you mean? (`cellattr`, `rowattr`, customm formatter and so on). The demo would clear the most questions.

Comment: @user4903642: Moreover I don't want to have "never ending story" in comments. You question was: `setRowData` takes almost 5 seconds when the grid has 300 rows, 30 cols, and 4 frozen cols. I suggested you to use free jqGrid and to reload the local data (from `data` parameter) instead on modification with `setRowData`. Do you tried this? The original time was 5 sec. How long is it now? I second recommendation was to reduce `rowNum` and to use paging instead. Do you tried this? How long is the time now? If you have **another** questions about jqGrid you can accept this one and post new one.

Comment: okay.there are 2 issues I am mixing. Sorry for that 
issue1) setRowData takes almost 5 seconds when grid has 300 rows, 30 cols, 4 frozen cols: Instead of setRowData,I tried reloadGrid datatype local but not significant gain in performance. Then I tried setCell, which seems to be faster. but customFormatter gets called. if you see defination of 'Discount' column above, there I am getting 'rowObject.level' undefined, also we can not use rowNum < 500.
2) Overall sluggishness with column,row combinations mentioned at start question above even with freeJqgrid. I will post separate for this.

Comment: @user4903642: I have still many questions opened. I can't understand what you do without to see the corresponding code. 1) What do you with `setRowData` and 300 rows? Do you modify the rows in the loop? In the case it will be slow. It's just the wrong way like I wrote before. **One should modify all the rows in one operation**. You need modify `data` array with items and call `reloadGrid`. The `datatype` have to be `"local"` at the moment. **Could you provide the demo which demonstrates what you do? I could modify it to show exactly which changes need be done.**

Comment: @Oleg-Below is the working demo link (with freeJQGrid). Please put numeric values in quantity and unit columns to see calculation in totals column. Usecase is single row edit for end users.
Looks good with 500 rows in the demo application with few columns but in real application we have more editable columns, CSS and formatting.
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CWzNFJRSuIQXZBMzM4R0ZQdHc/view?usp=sharing
With 500 overall scrolling,hovering bit slow and With 1000 rows, you will see lag with setRowData as well. Thanks really for your time.

Comment: @user4903642: Thanks, now I have some imagination what you do. I still not full understand the goal of the code. How it could be the *multiple rows* will be updated at once? If the user change a value in some cell then you want that `Process` function will be called. You have `this` which points already to `<input>`. To get the changed value you need just use `$(contrl).val()`. To get all data you need just use `$("#list").jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowId)` because you have `datatype: "local"`.  and so on. I can include a possible replacement of the code of `Process` function.

Comment: @user4903642: I posted possible replacement of `Process` function (I tested the code at my) and added descriptions of the code. I hope it will solve all performance problems.

Comment: thanks! setting cells with the help of index has given us the improvement of around 1.5 sec, which would be very helpful!